# Sorting connected wifi in listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-wifi

I am displaying available wifi in **listview** and I am connecting to wifi..
using dialog box in my android app..once wifi connected how to display that 
wifi name as first in listview..I want to display connected wifi as first in 
Listview..How can I do this?

```
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Name);
     textView.setText(accessPoints.get(i);
     textView.setOnClickListener(
     new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        final Dialog dialog =new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.password_dialog);
        final Button connect = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Button cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        connect.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
           list<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
           for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
           if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
           wifiManager.disconnect();
           wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
           wifiManager.reconnect();               
           break;
         }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WifiManager` class has a method `getConnectionInfo()`, which will return the `WifiInfo` object for the current connection. You can check the SSID `String` of this wifi and compare it with the `WifiConfiguration` list using a simple Java `Comparator` like this:

```
public static class WifiComparator implements Comparator<WifiConfiguration> {

    WifiInfo connectedInto;

    public WifiComparator(WifiInfo connectedInto) {
        this.connectedInto = connectedInto;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WifiConfiguration lhs, WifiConfiguration rhs) {
        if (connectedInto == null)
            return 0;
        else {
            if (lhs.SSID.equals(connectedInto.getSSID()))
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and then just sort the list by calling

```
Collections.sort(list, new WifiComparator(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo()));
```